# sendFile not a function in express-based Node app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, filepath

I have the following code in `server.js` (where app is an express instance), that is supposed to return a file `index.html` which is located  in the same directory as `server.js`.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var indexPath = path.resolve('index.html');
    res.sendFile(indexPath);
});
```

I log out `indexPath` and it is the correct path to my html file.  Yet I get the following error

> TypeError: res.sendFile is not a function

and call trace:

> ```
> at Object.handle (/Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/ABApp/server.js:54:9)
> at next_layer (/Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/ABApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
> at Route.dispatch (/Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/ABApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
> at /Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/ABApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24
> at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/ABApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)
> at next (/Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/ABApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
> at Layer.jsonParser [as handle] (/Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/ABApp/node_modules/body-parser/index.js:31:38)
> at trim_prefix (/Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/ABApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:226:17)
> at /Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/ABApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:198:9
> at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/ABApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)
> ```

Comment: What version of Express are you using?

Comment: i an using version ^4

Comment: What version exactly? `sendFile` is only available in 4.8.0+

Comment: i am not sure.  my package file has `"express": "^4",` , should I instead specify something like 4.8.0+?

Comment: Do `npm list` and see what version you get. If you need 4.8.0+ you'd do `^4.8.0`

Comment: i added 4.8.0 and ran npm install and now sendFile is recognized, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

In older versions of Express, the method used to be `senfile`, not `sendFile`.

Update to [Express 4.14](http://expressjs.com/en/changelog/4x.html#4.14.0), you will be able to use `sendFile`. 4.14 is also a security update, so it is highly recommended.

You can add this in your `package.json` file: `"express": "^4.14.0"`.